# Solicitando baixar o arquivo no meio da execução

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um pequeno problema, tenho uma execução no PHP que gera uma média de 34 mil *insert's* no MySQL, sendo isto feito via *stored procedure*.

Porém quando rodo a execução a mesma fica em torno de 5 minutos executando e do nada solicita o download do arquivo `XPTO.php`.

Mesmo assim a execução no banco continua.

O que posso fazer para resolver o problema?

Utilizo:

- Zend Server - 7.0.0
- MySQL - 5.5.40
- PHP - 5.4.24

Comment: Algum erro é retornado ? Onde está o código ?

Comment: não gera erro algum simplesmente para solicita o download do arquivo, pelo que entendi o o browser simplesmente para a execução. porem a execução no banco processa ate o final

Comment: Podemos assumir que **XPTO.php** é alguma biblioteca de terceiros e que você ja tomou as devidas precauções com relação ao tempo limite?

Comment: não pior que não é o arquivo que faz todo o procedimento e sim tomamos todos os cuidados com relação ao tempo limite

Comment: *Show us the code* :)

Comment: realmente não tenho como fazer isto, primeiro por ser algo de uma empresa muito grande. segundo é algo em torno de 4500 linhas, porem executa ate o final só que tenho esse procedimento de calculo em uma base de 3600000 registros gerando somente 35000 registros e fazendo o insert dos mesmos em outra tabela

Comment: Já que não pode compartilhar o código, tente compartilhar o conteúdo do arquivo XPTO.php (que seria o equivalente ao erro) e/ou os cabeçalhos HTTP de resposta (que seria pra ver porque o navegador resolveu fazer download do arquivo ao invés de mostrar na tela).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera descobri como resolver a questão.

No Zend Server temos essa configuração no `XML` padrão dele:

```
<Timeouts connectionTimeout="60" requestTimeout="120" />
```

Acabei trocando por:

```
<Timeouts connectionTimeout="60" requestTimeout="1500" />
```

Resolvendo assim meu problema.

Fico grato por todos que tentaram ajudar.

Comment: Acho que sua forma de resolver um erro pode criar outros piores...

Comment: a rotina foi validada varias vezes e cheguei nessa solução pois só ocorria nos computadores do desenvolvimento. entao fiz um diff com o servidor de produção chegando nessa solução

Comment: Você esta fazendo esse update de 3600000 registros durante 5 minutos - esse é o problema. O que vai acontecer se sua DB duplicar de tamanho?

Comment: nos temos uma permissa de deixar toda a  regra de negocio no banco de dados pois eles sao mantios pela ibm os servidores de aplicação sao mais simplorios

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso, acho aumentar o tempo de Timeout não e uma boa opção. 
Se o problema e o numero de INSERT, ao inves de fazer 34.000 você pode fazer uma so assim:

```
 INSERT INTO example
    (example_id, name, value, other_value)
 VALUES
   (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
   (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
   (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
   (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

Tambem, precisa saber porque você precisa fazer 34.000 INSERT... Se e para resolver um problema de tipo DUMP, você pode usar direitamente SQL sem usar PHP.

Para responder no comentário de Otto, dizendo que ele usa store_procedure,
isso:

```
 for ($test=0; $test<10; $test++)
 {
 $str = ""; 
     for ($w=0; $w < 3400; $w++)
     {
        $str .= "(".$w.",'Name1','Totpo','Name2'),\n";
    }
     $str .= "(".$w.",'Name1','Totpo','Name2');";

    $query_insert = "
    INSERT INTO EXEMPLE
    (champ1,champ2,champ3,champ4)
    VALUES ".$str;
    //echo $query_insert;
    $result = sql_query($db_so36,$query_insert);
 }
```

então, 34.000 INSERT, demora somente 0,271 seg !

Comment: os inserts são gerados via store procedure toda a execução é banco ... ou melhor toda a regra de negocio é banco de dados